# Null check operator used on a null value issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, null-check

I have the issue of _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value, its happened in openstreet map included in Flutter project when i choose service of car in rider app and greate reuest of ride.

check the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';
import 'package:ridy/generated/l10n.dart';
import '../graphql/generated/graphql_api.dart';
import 'bloc/main_bloc.dart';
import '../main/select_service_view.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';

class ServiceSelectionCardView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ServiceSelectionCardView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainBloc = context.read<MainBloc>();
    return BlocBuilder<MainBloc, MainBlocState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Mutation(
        options: MutationOptions(document: CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION_DOCUMENT),
        builder: (RunMutation runMutation, QueryResult? result) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      heroTag: 'cancelFab',
                      onPressed: () => mainBloc.add(ResetState()),
                      label: Text(S.of(context).action_cancel),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.close))
                  .pOnly(bottom: 8)
                  .objectCenterRight(),
              SelectServiceView(
                data: (state as OrderPreview).fareResult,
                onServiceSelect: (String serviceId, int intervalMinutes) async {
                  final args = CreateOrderArguments(
                          input: CreateOrderInput(
                              serviceId: int.parse(serviceId),
                              intervalMinutes: 0,
                              points: state.points
                                  .map((e) => PointInput(
                                      lat: e.point.latitude,
                                      lng: e.point.longitude))
                                  .toList(),
                              addresses:
                                  state.points.map((e) => e.address).toList()))
                      .toJson();
                  final result = await runMutation(args).networkResult;
                  //print(result!.data!.toString());
                  final _order =
                      CreateOrder$Mutation.fromJson(result!.data!).createOrder;
                  mainBloc.add(OrderUpdated(order: _order));
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

see this screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bang operator `!`, when you're 100% sure that the variable can't be `null`. Seems like `result.data` can in fact be `null`, if you log the result you will see that this is the case. You can try making a `null` check first before serializing the response :

```dart
if (result!=null){
 if (result!.data!=null){
  // result.data here is never `null`
 }
}
```

Comment: still the same error when but the statement inside if condition if (result!=null){
                      

                  final _order =
                      CreateOrder$Mutation.fromJson(result.data!).createOrder;
                  mainBloc.add(OrderUpdated(order: _order));
                  }

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 CreateOrder$Mutation.fromJson(result!.data!).createOrder;
```

with this one

```
 CreateOrder$Mutation.fromJson(result.data).createOrder;
```

Comment: still the same error stay

Answer (score 0):

Try below hope its help to you.you have put extra **`!`** null operator remove it. Refer **`Flutter Sound null safety`**
[here](https://dart.dev/null-safety) and [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Replace

```
result!.data!
```

to this

```
result!.data
```

Full declaration:

```
final _order = CreateOrder$Mutation.fromJson(result!.data).createOrder;
                  mainBloc.add(OrderUpdated(order: _order));
```

Comment: this declaration result!.data create error in the code

Comment: i think the error related with connect network and dont getting result final result = await runMutation(args).networkResult;